# incompatible - graph in java

Tags: java, graph

I get an error, incompatible types, vertex cannot be converted to String

```
public String removeVertex(Vertex v) {
    for (Edge e : incidentEdges(v)) {
        edges.remove(e);
        vertices.remove(v);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Please add code for `Edge` class

Comment: I suspect that you have included in a list a Vertex and and String object and then you are trying to sort the list. Typically you get error messages like this one in this situation: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Vertex cannot be cast to java.lang.String`. Is this the error you are getting?

Comment: I am trying to add to a doubly linked list

Comment: You try to return the argument v which is declared as a Vertex but the method declares a return type of String.

Comment: is there a way of fixing it without changing the method signature?

Comment: @okmijn it depends on your business logic. You could return some dummy string object or return String property of `Vertex` object or whatever you want